# Merge multiple Json objects while nesting them

Tags: javascript, json, express, sequelize.js

I am currently developing an endpoint where I want to return one object from 4 different tables. I get the record of each table in JSON format from sequelize. I have a location, service, staff, and Tenant. How can I merge them into one object but nested.
For example:
The data I get from sequelize for staff:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "profession": "Dentist",
    "note": "Good Man",
    "holidays": "Saturday",
    "specialDays": null,
    "createdAt": "2023-01-27T14:23:52.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-01-27T14:23:52.000Z",
}
```

All other data are in a similar format. But I want to merge them to return something like:

```
 {  staff:{
        "id": 2,
        "profession": "Dentist",
        "note": "Good Man",
        "holidays": "Saturday",
        "specialDays": null,
        "createdAt": "2023-01-27T14:23:52.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-01-27T14:23:52.000Z",},
    location:{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Branch 1",
        "address": "37 Automatic Handling",
        "description": "This is our main branch",
        "latitude": "564233",
        "longtitude": "4441256",
        "visible": true,
        "createdAt": "2023-01-27T14:05:37.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-01-27T14:05:37.000Z",
    }
           
       

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an object yourself

```js
// (inside of an async function)

const location = await // sequelize code to get this info
const service = await // sequelize code to get this info
const staff = await // sequelize code to get this info
const tenant = await // sequelize code to get this info

return res.json({
  location,
  service,
  staff,
  Tenant: tenant, // remove "Tenant: " if the capital was a typo or you don't care
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```js
const staff = {
    "id": 2,
    "profession": "Dentist",
    "note": "Good Man",
    "holidays": "Saturday",
    "specialDays": null,
    "createdAt": "2023-01-27T14:23:52.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-01-27T14:23:52.000Z",
};

const location1 = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Branch 1",
    "address": "37 Automatic Handling",
    "description": "This is our main branch",
    "latitude": "564233",
    "longtitude": "4441256",
    "visible": true,
    "createdAt": "2023-01-27T14:05:37.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-01-27T14:05:37.000Z",
};

const mergedObject = { staff, location1 };
console.log(mergedObject);
```

Comment: Works great! Just changed it to const mergedObject = { staff:staff, location: location1 }; to control the name but other than that it works flawlessly